# Stop other processes & prevent logins while Jenkins job is running

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I want Jenkins jobs to run exclusively on a server to measure CPU performance. There should not be any other people logged in the server. Is there a way todo it using Jenkins? Or are there any other CI tools that automatically kick out logged in users & running processes. I can grant root access to the CI tool.

Comment: Can you add more info on the server? Can solution be adding IP white list to server?

Comment: @user7294900 Do you mean that I can add sth like `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24` to my Jenkins job config? How about kicking out other users? My server has the latest Ubuntu LTS version.